# write to local file in angular service

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have tho following angular service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { person } from '../interfaces/iperson';
import { item } from '../interfaces/iitem';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PeopleserviceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPersonData(): Observable<person[]> {
    return this.http.get<person[]>('/assets/data/people.json');
  }
  completeTransaction(p: person, i: item){
    return this.http.get<person[]>('/assets/data/people.json').toPromise().then(peopleData => {
      if (!peopleData) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('No data received'));
      }

      for (const pers of peopleData) {
        if (pers.id === p.id) {
          pers.balance -= i.price;
          break;
        }
      }

      return this.http.put('/assets/data/people.json', JSON.stringify(peopleData)).toPromise();
    });
  }
}
```

but it gives the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","url":"http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/data/people.json","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:4200/assets/data/people.json: 404 Not Found","error":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot PUT /assets/data/people.json</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"}
    Angular 17
core.mjs:9171:22
    Angular 2
    RxJS 6
    Angular 14
```

How would I make this angular page running locally write to a file?

I have looked into the localforage package, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `PUT` is used for updating a restful resource, not persisting data to disk. You will probably need to use something like file-saver and return a blob from your service instead.

Comment: Your HTTP server gave a 404 Not Found response to the PUT request. Presumably this is because you haven't done anything to make the HTTP server support PUT requests. You need to look at writing server side code to support it; the client side code you've provided is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

`assets/data/people.json` lives on the server. When you are one Localhost, the client and the server are on the same computer, but usually the server is somewhere remote.
You cannot just write into a file on a server, if you want to do that you have to create a backend (i.e. NodeJS with Express) and create an endpoint that accepts some data, then on the Server you can write data on your file.

Keep in mind that this file is share with all the user, it's not a personal copy.

Comment: it's always meant to be ran on one computer, would it be possible then?

Comment: idk why this was downvoted ;) anyway you can create a copy of people.json and download it using file-saver `saveAs` function.  This will be a copy, you can't edit the original file. https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver you will find many exaples of how to save a .txt or a .json on google.